# Bootstrap Fileupload removes img tag on cancel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have the following html:

```
<div id="#course_logo_container" class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
    <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" /> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>
            <span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have added the bootstrap-fileupload.js to the head.

My problem is that when I select an image and then try to select another but cancel the action, the image tag is removed thus removing the last picture.

So I searched in the documentation of bootstrap about some js api that could prevent this behaviour, but I couldn't find anything.

Can someone tell me where I could find that?